# Storing elements of one Array into another in Reverse Order

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have 2 `String` `array`s with the same lengths and I wanted to store the elements of the first into the other in reverse order.

This approach doesn't seem to work and I can't wrap my head around why.

```java
for (int i = (originalArray.length) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int j = 0;
    reverseOrderArray[j] = originalArray[i];
    j++;
}
```

The elements of the first array are `{"1", "2", "3"}`

The output from the second array seems to be `{"1", null, null}`

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger; it'll save you a lot of time in the not-so-long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `j` to 0 a the top of each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
String[] a ={"10","20","30","40","50"};

Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(a)); 

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how and why your proposal helps.

Answer (score 0):

set `j=0` before starting the  for loop.if it's inside the for loop , with every iteration its value is set to be   0.